# How to implement basic CRUD actions for any model in Golang?

Tags: go, sqlite

I'm implementing a database API. I have models. I need to implement CRUD actions to each model. For now I create an individual `GetAllModels` function and `Get` method for each model. How could I do that once for all models and just pass around some variables if needed?

The pattern below I use for each model:

```
type City struct {
    Attr1 string
    Attr2 string
}

type Country struct {
    Attr1 string
    Attr2 string
}

func GetAllCities(db *sqlx.DB) ([]*City, error) {
    items := []*City{}
    err := db.Select(&items, "SELECT * FROM cities")
    // check err
    return items, nil
}

func (m *City) Get(db *sqlx.DB, id string) error {
    if err := db.Get(m, "SELECT FROM cities WHERE id = ?", id); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func GetAllCountries(db *sqlx.DB) ([]*Country, error) {
    items := []*Country{}
    err := db.Select(&items, "SELECT * FROM countries")
    // check err
    return items, nil
}

func (m *Country) Get(db *sqlx.DB, id string) error {
    if err := db.Get(m, "SELECT FROM countries WHERE id = ?", id); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

But what actually changes from model to model is a *query string* and a *type* of slice objects.

How to make one universal `GetAll` function and `Get` method for all future models?

Comment: I see the question was downvoted. Could anybody please explain why?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I am wondering what a Model's role here is. I could see it used as an abstract class in an object-oriented language, but I don't see how it would be useful as anything other that. What exactly does a Model do?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. I don't want to create an abstract class. I've updated the code sample in the question, please, take a look. I have several structs. And have very similar functions and methods to get data from the DB. Each such function has identical structure but different *query string* and different *type*. So I think these funcs don't have to be different funcs, they could be the only set of CRUD funcs but with different variables. But I'm stuck in implementing this.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, when I was answering you the post had been deleted. Don't know who and why.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but it should work. If you receive the table and column names (or you know them) for each request and you can just fetch from the db as `interface` passing the table and column as variables.

package main

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

func selectAll(table string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", table)
}

func selectWhere(table string, column string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = ?", table, column)
}

func validTableStr(table string) bool {
    // real validation here
    return true
}

func validColumnStr(table string, column string) bool {
    // real validation here
    return true
}

func GetAll(db *sqlx.DB, table string) ([]interface{}, error) {

    if !validTableStr(table) {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid table name")
    }

    items := []interface{}{}
    err := db.Select(&items, selectAll(table))
    return items, err
}

func GetWhere(db *sqlx.DB, table string, column string, value interface{}) ([]interface{}, error) {

    if !validTableStr(table) {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid table name")
    }

    if !validColumnStr(table, column) {
        return nil, errors.New("invalid column name")
    }

    items := []interface{}{}
    err := db.Select(&items, selectWhere(table, column), value)
    return items, err
}
```